# TypeError: _new_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm getting a TypeError and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here the type error is `TypeError: _new_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` which I'm assuming means I would need to instantiate a class instance?

This is what I've done as you can see I've added `message = ctx.message` to the code.

Here is what I'm workng with:

```
class antilink:
"""
Anti URL spam
"""

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.regex = re.compile(r"<?(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(discord\.gg|discordapp\.com\/invite)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9/]*)>?")
    self.regex_discordme = re.compile(r"<?(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(discord\.me\/)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9/]*)>?")
    self.regex_url = re.compile(r'(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))')


async def _new_message(self, ctx, message):
    """Finds the message and checks it for regex"""
    server = ctx.message.server
    user = message.author
    excluded = []
    message = ctx.message
    if ctx.message.server:
        if self.regex.search(ctx.message.content) is not None or self.regex_discordme.search(ctx.message.content) is not None \
            or self.regex_url.search(ctx.message.content)is not None and ctx.message.server:

                roles = [r.name for r in user.roles]
                bot_admin = settings.get_server_admin(ctx.message.server)
                bot_mod = settings.get_server_mod(ctx.message.server)
                if ctx.message.channel.id is excluded:
                    return
                elif user.id == settings.owner:
                    return
                elif bot_admin in roles:
                    return
                elif bot_mod in roles:
                    return
                elif user.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).manage_messages is True:
                    return
                else:
                    asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                    await self.bot.delete_message(message)


def setup(bot):
    q = antilink(bot)
    bot.add_listener(q._new_message, 'on_message')
    bot.add_cog(q)
```

If anyone could help me out here I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `message` argument. Plus you are not using it in your function anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're registering `q._new_message` as an [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) callback, then it will be called with the same arguments `on_message` is, which means a single `Message` argument that represents the message that was sent.

```
async def _new_message(self, message):
    """Finds the message and checks it for regex"""
    server = message.server
    user = message.author
    excluded = []
    if server:
        if self.regex.search(message.content) is not None or self.regex_discordme.search(message.content) is not None \
            or self.regex_url.search(message.content)is not None and message.server:

                roles = [r.name for r in user.roles]
                bot_admin = settings.get_server_admin(message.server)
                bot_mod = settings.get_server_mod(message.server)
                if message.channel.id is excluded:
                    return
                elif user.id == settings.owner:
                    return
                elif bot_admin in roles:
                    return
                elif bot_mod in roles:
                    return
                elif user.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages is True:
                    return
                else:
                    asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                    await self.bot.delete_message(message)
```

You could also just define a `async def on_message(self, message)` method, which the `add_cog` machinery will automatically register as a callback for the event of that name.